# List of react-native StyleSheet properties and options

Tags: reactjs, stylesheet, react-native

I've been searching the web for a list of all the possible react-native StyleSheet options and their values. Not to be found, does anyone have a link to such a documentation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here they are, separated by component type:

[View](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props)

[Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#style)

[Text](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style)

[Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#content)

[Transform](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms.html#props)

Where you see enum in the documentation, for example on the Text style documentation page:

```
fontStyle enum('normal', 'italic')
fontWeight enum("normal", 'bold', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900')
```

These usually closely resemble css properties you would find on the web.

---

**UPDATE**

As answered below by @muhammad-hannan, you can also find [the full layout properties list there](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html).

Comment: As of 0.44, View's style is empty. But 0.43 has style reference. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/view.html#style

Comment: [View] (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/view.html#style) link is down

Answer (score 5):

I know this has been answered but since last updates things have been changed. The updated stylesheet properties can be found below, which are now called layout props now:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html

**Layout `Props` List:**

```
marginHorizontal
alignContent
alignSelf
aspectRatio
borderBottomWidth
borderEndWidth
borderLeftWidth
borderRightWidth
borderStartWidth
borderTopWidth
borderWidth
bottom
display
end
flex
flexBasis
flexDirection
flexGrow
flexShrink
flexWrap
height
justifyContent
left
margin
marginBottom
marginEnd
alignItems
marginLeft
marginRight
marginStart
marginTop
marginVertical
maxHeight
maxWidth
minHeight
minWidth
overflow
padding
paddingBottom
paddingEnd
paddingHorizontal
paddingLeft
paddingRight
paddingStart
paddingTop
paddingVertical
position
right
start
top
width
zIndex
direction
```