# CSS animation and transformation in react-native

Tags: css, react-native

Just wondering if we can use CSS animation and transformation in react-native?
i.e.

```
 <Image style={animateImage} / >

StyleSheet.create({

 animateImage {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   transition: width 3s;
   transition-delay: 1s;
 }

});
```

Answer (score 16):

No, you cannot. React Native's [`Stylesheet` properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34317028) are pretty limited when compared with vanilla CSS.

For animations look into the [Animated API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use CSS animations and transformations in React Native.
There is a Keyframes library for React-Native called [react-native-facebook-keyframes](https://github.com/underscopeio/react-native-facebook-keyframes). It might be what you need instead.

Comment: Not sure which version of RN this was about, but for some time you can do transforms indeed. https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms