# React native drawer menu: can`t find variable styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a slider menu with the [react-native-drawer-menu](https://github.com/Tinysymphony/react-native-drawer-menu) module. After installing the module . get an error can`t find variable styles. This is the code copied from the example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import'../I18n/I18n.js';
import RootContainer from './RootContainer'
import createStore from '../Redux'
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer-menu';
import {Easing} from 'react-native'; // Customize easing function (Optional)

// create store
const store = createStore()

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  // prepare your drawer content 
  var drawerContent = (<View style={styles.drawerContent}>
    <View style={styles.leftTop}/>
    <View style={styles.leftBottom}>
      <View><Text>Drawer Content</Text></View>
    </View>
  </View>);
  var customStyles = {
    drawer: {
      shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowOpacity: 0.4,
      shadowRadius: 10
    },
    mask: {}, // style of mask if it is enabled 
    main: {} // style of main board 
  };
  return (
    <Drawer
      style={styles.container}
      drawerWidth={300}
      drawerContent={drawerContent}
      type={Drawer.types.Overlay}
      customStyles={{drawer: styles.drawer}}
      drawerPosition={Drawer.positions.Right}
      onDrawerOpen={() => {console.log('Drawer is opened');}}
      onDrawerClose={() => {console.log('Drawer is closed')}}
      easingFunc={Easing.ease}
    >
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text>{Object.values(Drawer.positions).join(' ')}</Text>
        <Text>{Object.values(Drawer.types).join(' ')}</Text>
      </View>
    </Drawer>
  );
}
}
```

If I delete the variable from the code then the slide menu works but looks extremely bad.

[image]

Do you think that I am supposed to create the style of the menu on my own or shall I imported from somewhere? If I have to create it, how can I know which parameters did it take? Or is it a normal view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to add styles by yourself to make look Drawer content exactly as you want to. To achieve it you have to create [Stylesheet](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html)

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34317028/4347646) answer to get more info about React Native  Stylesheet properties (it's pretty much similar to css)

Also maybe this example from drawer repo would be [helpful](https://github.com/Tinysymphony/react-native-drawer-menu/blob/2527ddf55a4e789bf9c8cf7ab169799182f1e758/index.ios.js#L95)

Cheers.